# "undefined method DOMDocument::addChild()" on simple create XML sript

Tags: php, xml

I'm getting an error on the following snippet:

```
1 $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
2 $xml->formatOutput = TRUE; // enable automatic indenting
3   $xml->loadXML('<songData/>'); // set root node  
4   $song       = $xml->addChild('song');
5   $artist     = $xml->addChild('artist');
6   
7   echo $xml->asXML();
```

That returns:

```
Call to undefined method DOMDocument::addChild() on line 4
```

What is going on to trigger this error?

Edit, Ultimately I am going for something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<songData>
    <song>
        <title>Carbona Not Glue</title>
        <artist>Ramones</artist>
        <members>
            <name>Johny</name>
            <name>Joey</name>
            <name>Dee Dee</name>
           <name>Marky</name>
        </members>
    </song>
</songData>
```

Comment: Maybe because there is no `addChild` method? Did you mean to use [`appendChild`](http://www.php.net/manual/domnode.appendchild.php)

Answer (score 0):

Which XML are you trying to create exactly, could you post an example? If what you want if something like `<songData><song><artist></artist></song></songData>`, you can do that using the `createElement` function:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = TRUE; // enable automatic indenting

// Create the element
$rootElement = $xml->createElement('songData'); // set root node  
$songElement = $xml->createElement('song');
$artistElement = $xml->createElement('artist');

// Add them to the DOM
$xml->appendChild($rootElement);
$rootElement->appendChild($songElement);
$songElement->appendChild($artistElement);

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error on your example: `Call to undefined method DOMElement::createElement()`

Comment: There was some problem with the code. All the elements should be created from the DOMDocument object, then appended using the `appendChild()` method. I've updated my example.

Comment: It's [`saveXML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) - not `asXML()`.